# Expected known function, got 'MD5'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to do a search like this:

```
//Project\MyBundle\Repository

$query = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('ProjectMyBundle:Product')->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->where('MD5(p.id) = :id')
        ->setParameter('id', $id )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleResult();
```

I get the id on MD5 and have to search for an id on MD5 in the database.

When I do a search, I showed up, gives me the following error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 51: Error: Expected known function, got 'MD5'

Indicated that lib:

https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/Md5.php

But I've put it inside the folder and now I need to know where it should matter.

I am using MySQL, Doctrine 2.2 in Symfony 2.1.6.

Comment: Which DBS you are using?

Comment: I am using Mysql, Doctrine 2.2 in Symfony 2.1.6

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to register MD5 as a custom DQL function:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    orm:
        # ...
        entity_managers:
            default:
                # ...
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        MD5: Acme\HelloBundle\DQL\MD5Function
```

For more info, see: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/custom_dql_functions.html