# Substring_index function in doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have to use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function in doctrine ORM in symfony 2. How can I do this? Right now using it inside the query gives me undefined function error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 299: Error: Expected known function, got 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'
```

I use this function to get the first number from, for example:

```
11.48.205.1
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14437229/expected-known-function-got-md5 ?

Comment: There's no substring_index class in doctrine to register it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is class that represent SUBSTRING_INDEX function (don't forget to update namespace).

```
<?php

namespace Sad\Functions;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;

/**
 * "SUBSTRING_INDEX" "(" ArithmeticPrimary "," ArithmeticPrimary "," ArithmeticPrimary ")"
 *
 * @author  Andrey Stepanov <stepashka@gmail.com>
 */
class SubstringIndexFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $str = null;
    public $delim = null;
    public $count = null;

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'SUBSTRING_INDEX(' .
            $this->str->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
            $this->delim->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
            $this->count->dispatch($sqlWalker) .
        ')';
    }

    /**
     * @override
     */
    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->str = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->delim = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->count = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

You need to register it before creating entity manager:

```
$config->addCustomStringFunction('SUBSTRING_INDEX', 'Sad\Functions\SubstringIndexFunction');
/* ... */
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
```

After you do it you'll get the following results:

```
echo $entityManager->createQuery("SELECT p FROM \Sad\Schema\AbstractPageAny as p WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(p.name,'a',1) = 'P'")->getSQL();
// Output: SELECT p0_.id AS id_0, p0_.name AS name_1, p0_.type AS type_2 FROM page p0_ WHERE (SUBSTRING_INDEX(p0_.name, 'a', 1) = 'P')
```