# Simple IF test statement in Doctrine

Tags: mysql, doctrine

Does Doctrine support IF statements? I get the following error:

```
Expected known function, got 'IF'
```

while executing this query with IF:

```
$qb->select("c.id, IF(c.type_id LIKE 9, c.name, c.lastname) as name")
```

It works fine while re-written in pure SQL. Any workarounds?

Comment: This answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504632/substring-index-function-in-doctrine-orm/25508062#25508062 . You can create function class and register it for Doctrine to use it. But, as mentioned below, consider if you really need IF there.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes `if` statements in doctrine is not supported you may convert it to `case when`

```
IF(c.type_id LIKE 9, c.name, c.lastname) as name
```

to

```
case when c.type_id = 9 then c.name else c.lastname end as name
```

**UPDATE:**
From the comment does `concat` function is allowed in `case-when`

The answer is yes very much allowed. Here is an example

```
mysql> select * from timesheets ;
+-----------+-------+----------+
| client_id | hours | category |
+-----------+-------+----------+
|         1 |  1.50 | onsite   |
|         1 |  1.50 | onsite   |
|         1 |  1.00 | remote   |
|         2 |  1.50 | remote   |
+-----------+-------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select 
case when category = 'onsite' then concat('ON',' ',hours) else hours
end as dd from timesheets ;
+---------+
| dd      |
+---------+
| ON 1.50 |
| ON 1.50 |
| 1.00    |
| 1.50    |
+---------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: O.K. thanks for the reply. But does case when statement support concatenation?

Comment: Yes the `concat()` could be used in `case when`.

Answer (score 8):

> *Note*: for **Doctrine 2**

Think it's better to use some extra functional in such cases ( without trying "to circumvent" theirs). E.g. an excellent solution adding almost all necessary ( not supported from box ) stuff for `Doctrine 2` is  [DoctrineExtensions by beberlei](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) (github). With it it's possible to use directly `IF`-statement like in OP's case:

("Symfony-example") E.g. in your `config.xml` add lines:

```
orm:
    ..
    entity_managers:
            ....
            dql:
                ....
                string_functions:
                    IF: DoctrineExtensions\Query\Mysql\IfElse
```

Then U can use it anywhere like:

```
 $qb->select("..IF(condition, true-state, false-state)...")
```

Comment: Objection: Raising the number of used bundles also raises the exposure to conflicting ones, or to ones that will stop being maintained one day. While adapting yourself to another way of doing the same thing limits it.

Comment: @Moonchild I don't agree: this particular extention is well documented (its documentation is available on Symfony's own documentation), well known, and well maintained. It clarifies your code especially if you begin to use several SQL functions and you don't have to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @Erdal G. I totally agree with you, I don't see how your comment opposes to mine. This bundle is awesome, I use it a lot. But if you can do without a bundle, just by changing your syntax,  it is always better.

Comment: @Moonchild then we are totally in phase :)  Even more here where OP's need does indeed correspond perfectly to `CASE`. As `IF ` is designed for control flow, where `CASE` determines which value to pick from columns