# Symfony Doctrine - If else in query builder

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I want to choose the joined table by the result of one field from other.

In detail there is a field catId. This is the id of the category with a letter s or c in front. And if there is a c like c6 i must join the category table and look there for the id. If s, i have to join the subcategory table and look for the id. So i also have to cut the letter in front of the result.

How can i do this in query builder directly in the code?
I hope this explains it:

```
public function contentByNId($NId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->where('c.news = :news')
        ->setParameter('news', $NId)

        // the result from c.catId as a number with s for subcategory or c for category in front. like s21 or c6

        // if in c.catID is an s than
        // cut the letter (s or c) from c.catId for the leftJoin to  replacedCatID
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:subcategories', 's', 'WITH', 'c.replacedCatID = s.id')
        //
        //
        //  else
        //
        //
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:categories', 's', 'WITH', 'c.replacedCatID = s.id')
        //
        //

        ->addSelect(
            'c',
            's.headline'
        )
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple IF test statement in Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792968/simple-if-test-statement-in-doctrine)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function contentByNId($NId)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
    .....................
    if(//your logic) {
        .....................
        $qb->leftJoin('AppBundle:subcategories', 's', 'WITH', 'c.replacedCatID = s.id')
        .................................
    }
    else {
        .....................
        $qb->leftJoin('AppBundle:categories', 's', 'WITH', 'c.replacedCatID = s.id')
        .................................
    }

    return $qb->getQuery();
}
```

Comment: if i send this value to the function - i think your idea is correct. But i have to get this values in the query...and this is what i don't know to do.