# How to use IF statement in Doctrine Query Builder select

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a doctrine statement to get all the fields from a table

```
->createQueryBuilder()
->select('u')
->from(User::class, 'u')
```

How can I add to this select an additional column based on a value in another column? This would be the mysql equivalent:

```
SELECT 
    u.*,
    IF(u.group = 1, 'Yes', 'No') as isAdmin
  FROM user u ...
```

I need to know how to do this in doctrine. Thanks.

Comment: You need to use case in the select. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html

Comment: I need to know how to do it in doctrine.

Comment: SELECT 
    ....
    case when u.group = 1 then 'YES' else 'NO'
    end as isAdmin
    ....

Comment: As I told use CASE in ->select().

Comment: @user3174311 Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792968/simple-if-test-statement-in-doctrine ?