# SUBSTRING_INDEX not recognised in Doctrine 2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a Symfony 3 CRM, and I need to be able to create a list of customers which can be filtered by the first letter of the surname. The issue is, I need to split the column data first in order to find the surname - this is because the database is synced with Sage which requires data in a specific format so I cannot change it.

I discovered the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` function and tried it out in my mySQL software and it works perfectly - so I tried to incorporate it into a DQL query like so:

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT u FROM AppBundle:Customer c WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(c.contact_name, ' ', 3), ' ', -1) LIKE :letter");
$query->setParameter('letter','%'.$letter.'%');
```

Where `$letter` is passed via a request from the CRM. However, I get the following error from Symfony when attempting to run:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 41: Error: Expected known function, got
>   'SUBSTRING_INDEX'

My guess is that Doctrine does not recognise the SUBSTRING_INDEX function? Is there an alternative way of doing what I need to, or a way to allow Doctrine to recognise this function?

Comment: you can use [this bundle](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) or     implements by yourself as described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25508062/2270041) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine doesn't recognize SUBSTRING_INDEX as a function.

You can import a [Doctrine Extension](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions) to recognize it or change your query for a thing lke this `sql LOWER(SUBSTRING(c.contact_name, LOCATE(' ', c.contact_name)-1))`